# How did i get and Session Var into an function

Tags: php

my problem is that i did not get an php session variable into my function - i start in the top of the file

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

this is the result

```
array(3) { ["loggedin"]=> bool(true) ["name"]=> string(4) "Piet" ["id_staff"]=> int(9) }
```

```
public static function getStaffList($_SESSION['name']){

  if ($_SESSION['name'] =="admin" || $_SESSION['name'] =="Piet") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM staff";
  }
  else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM staff where surname = '".$_SESSION['name']."'";
  }

  $result = Core::$link->query($sql);

  if (!$result) {
    return 'Error: ' . mysqli_error(Core::$link);
  }

  $return = array();
  while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($myrow['birthday'] !== '0000-00-00') {
      $myrow['birthday'] = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($myrow['birthday']));
    } else {
      $myrow['birthday'] = '';
    }

    $return[] = $myrow;
  }

  return $return;
}
```

Comment: `function getStaffList($_SESSION['name'])` makes no sense. You can't specify a session value as the name of an input argument to a function. I expect this is causing an error? If you get an error, please [edit] your question to mention exactly what it is.

Comment: Anyway don't need to try to pass a Session value into your function like that - `$_SESSION` is already accessible everywhere in your script (as long as you use `session_start()` at the beginning, which you have done).

Comment: the $sql query has no data

Comment: Ok. That's a completely different problem, though. And how do you know exactly? Are you saying that `$return` is empty when you execute the function? At the moment it should be crashing completely, with the code you've shown us.

Comment: so you mean - that i can write it in that way function getStaffList() - because the variable is every wher?

Comment: Yes. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php: _"This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods."_

Comment: okay - done - but still have no access to the variable - sorry forgot it´s in an class ----- class Core { than the function ---- makes that an differnce?

Comment: What do you mean? Try to provide details please, not vague assertions. Put `public static function getStaffList($_SESSION['name']){
 var_dump($_SESSION);` . When you call `getStaffList()` from your code, what does the output of the var_dump show? It should show the same thing you showed us in your question. Which means that `$sql` should then be `SELECT * FROM staff`, and it should then return all rows from the database (if you have any). So then what happens later - does `$return` contain any data? Again, provide some meaningful debugging details please. We cannot see your data.

Comment: result is empty - no message

Comment: Sorry I should have said, put `public static function getStaffList(){
 var_dump($_SESSION);`  . Otherwise it will crash again, obviously

Comment: `sorry forgot it´s in an class ----- class Core { than the function ---- makes that an differnce?`...no, that makes no difference at all.

Comment: Do you call that method on the same page (where `session_start();` is)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem - run this demo: https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/ab6c98bd3261124da9f9cf368ef03f66/php/php81/641177b3fb13c925685e7e2f38d59c3d/ . I can only assume that maybe your `session_start()` is not in the same file as your getStaffList function, and isn't in a file which is included/required in the same overall script. I don't think we have a [mre] of the issue, so it's difficult to help any further until you update the question with more clarity.

Comment: i know - my problem is - that my calendar works local with xampp but not at my webserver

Comment: if i write exactly this after session_start() - $_SESSION = array("loggedin"=> true, "name"=>"Piet", "id_staff"=> 9); - than it works

Comment: `my calendar works local with xampp but not at my webserver`...and you didn't think that was relevant before??? Maybe your server has a configuration problem which is causing it not to save sessions properly, or something.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pass the session as parmeter:

```
public static function getStaffList($_SESSION['name']){
```

the session is available anyway:

```
public static function getStaffList(){
```

Take care that the call for the `session_start()` is executed at the start of the script.

Another point where you need to take care is using values directly into SQL statements!

```
  else {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM staff where surname ='".$_SESSION['name']."'";
  }
```

you never know what the user puts in there, or what value reaches to that point, and is than used for the query, leaking data.

Comment: is it wrong in my code?

Comment: RATHER, you should not use a global variable in a method, but always pass it as a parameter, either for this method or a constructor

Answer (score -3):

if i write exactly this after session_start() - $_SESSION = array("loggedin"=> true, "name"=>"Piet", "id_staff"=> 9); - than it works –

Comment: But this code makes no sense? It will just use same values regardless to what is actually stored in the session?

Comment: how you will do it

Comment: sorry - i know - will only show that  the script works - but the session ?